# Any other option to add the image in google wallet event ticket pass except URI

Tags: google-wallet

Need a solution for that, I have a image as buffer(or inputstream) but the wallet ticket pass accept only URI format. I know it's possible with Google Cloud Storage(But that also don't have). Please help me.

I tried this(new Set(['localhost', 'port_address']).has(new URL(imageHost).hostname))
that also no result